# How to best repair a lost or broken partition on a valued external hard drive without losing data

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, recovery

Can an unallocated external hard drive be repartitioned directly and made usable without losing data and without need to reformat?  (Windows 10, 64 bit)

My external hard drive's partition has for reason been rendered "unallocated".  There is nearly 5 terabytes of information stored therein.  I assume the partition is either lost or damaged. Is there any secure method and/or program available that will both diagnose and fix the partition without having to rescue all the data through time-consuming recovery and reformatting in order to make it usable?

I realize I am asking for a lot. So I am currently using EASEUS and scanning the drive.  The data so far appears salvageable, but this isn't yet confirmed. Looking forward, future reference would be very helpful- specially if it is available online- as I am living in a faraway place with little good tech help or equipment available.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From what I've heard TestDisk can recover partition information (https://www.cgsecurity.org/testdisk_doc/partition_recovery.html) but any writing to that disk is considered risky. Out of preference you would create a clone of that disk to some other location before you go modifying it.

Comment: Just reiterating @Mokubai comment -- *any* attempt to *repair* the drive will likely cause further loss of data. 1. Make an image. 2. Then attempt to recover data, first from the image, and then the drive itself, if all could not be recovered. 3. Finally, if you want to keep using the drive, remove all partitions, format and check for damage, both repairable and permanently bad sectors.

Comment: Why do you want to this? Is it because you don’t have another equal or larger volume to copy the data to? All the advice here is solid; you need to copy the raw data off of that drive if you want to hope to salvage it. And then you need to sift through that data to recover. No other way unless you want to risk the loss of all data.

Answer (score 2):

The best answer is "don't".

Yes unallocated does point to a missing partition table entry. But people working in data recovery will always assume there's more to it (potentially) and so default is to **extract data** rather then **fixing in-place**.

**Extracting data** can be done using file recovery tools like [DMDE](https://dmde.com/), R-Studio or a freebee like [Partition Find and Mount](http://findandmount.com/).

If you decide for whatever reason to take the more risky approach of fixing in -place DMDE can help too.

**Undeleting a partition using DMDE**

[image]

I am not going to state the obvious like 'select the physical drive' etc.

In **Disk** menu pick **Device I/O Parameters**, we need to switch the tool to write enabled.
[image]

Locate the lost/deleted partition in DMDE:
[image]

Select it, click **Open Volume** to inspect contents. To undelete it however, enable **Advanced Options**:
[image]

Now the **Edit** button becomes available which we can use to undelete the partition:
[image]

From there follow prompts and dialogs.

Video available here: https://youtu.be/F2PgrcxXrg8